# Toggle images on click with associated IDs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a repeated component with a control that toggles between displaying 2 images (mobile image and desktop image). I need each control to only toggle the component it is in, and function independently from every other component.

I am able to generate unique ids for all the controls, unique ids for all the images, and on click I am able to add/remove classes as well as show/hide images. My problem is that I don't know how to associate the toggle control id to the image id so that I'm only changing one component. Right now I am targeting the class (which is the same for every component) so everything toggles when you click the control.

This is inside Wordpress using Visual Composer, so I don't believe I am able to use a loop to render the repeated components.

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/schrdr/f5wzx317/16/)

#### below is a single component, which would be repeated a number of times

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="platform-toggle">
    <div class="mobile-toggle">
      mobile
    </div>
    <div class="desktop-toggle">
      desktop
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="platform-images">
    <img class="mobile-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=mobile" />
    <img class="desktop-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=desktop" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$.each($('.platform-toggle'), function(ind) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'platform-toggle_' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});

$.each($('.mobile-toggle'), function(ind) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'mobile-toggle_' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});

$.each($('.desktop-toggle'), function(ind) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'desktop-toggle_' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});

$.each($('.mobile-image'), function(ind) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'mobile-image_' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});

$.each($('.desktop-image'), function(ind) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'desktop-image_' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});

$(".mobile-toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(".mobile-toggle").hasClass("inactive")) {

    $(".mobile-toggle").removeClass("inactive");
    $(".mobile-toggle").addClass("active");
    $(".mobile-image").show()

    $(".desktop-toggle").removeClass("active");
    $(".desktop-toggle").addClass("inactive");
    $(".desktop-image").hide()
  }
});

$(".desktop-toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(".desktop-toggle").hasClass("inactive")) {

    $(".desktop-toggle").removeClass("inactive");
    $(".desktop-toggle").addClass("active");
    $(".desktop-image").show()

    $(".mobile-toggle").removeClass("active");
    $(".mobile-toggle").addClass("inactive");
    $(".mobile-image").hide()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use **$(this)** selector for this case, and jQuery has lot of functions for finding parent, sibling, children, next, prev or etc elements.

I've changed your fiddle and added new selectors.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jptLbs8e/)

```
$(".mobile-toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("inactive")) {
    $(this).removeClass("inactive");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    //find current toggle element parent, then find next element(wrapper of the images) and finally find children image.
    $(this).parent('.platform-toggle').next('.platform-images').children('.mobile-image').show();

    $(this).siblings('.desktop-toggle').removeClass("active");
    $(this).siblings('.desktop-toggle').addClass("inactive");
    $(this).parent('.platform-toggle').next('.platform-images').children('.desktop-image').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for your time and quick help.

Comment: It's possible to simplify some of that with chaining, like : `$(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active")` and `$(this).siblings('.desktop-toggle').removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");`

Answer (score 0):

You may use parent div of the specific control in this way:

```
$(".mobile-toggle").click(function() {
var parentObj=$(this).closest(".wrapper");
if ($(parentObj).find(".mobile-toggle").hasClass("inactive")) {
 $(parentObj).find(".mobile-toggle").removeClass("inactive");
 $(parentObj).find(".mobile-toggle").addClass("active");
 $(parentObj).find(".mobile-image").show()

 $(parentObj).find(".desktop-toggle").removeClass("active");
 $(parentObj).find(".desktop-toggle").addClass("inactive");
 $(parentObj).find(".desktop-image").hide()
}
});

$(".desktop-toggle").click(function() {
var parentObj=$(this).closest(".wrapper");
if ($(parentObj).find(".desktop-toggle").hasClass("inactive")) {

$(parentObj).find(".desktop-toggle").removeClass("inactive");
$(parentObj).find(".desktop-toggle").addClass("active");
$(parentObj).find(".desktop-image").show()

$(parentObj).find(".mobile-toggle").removeClass("active");
$(parentObj).find(".mobile-toggle").addClass("inactive");
$(parentObj).find(".mobile-image").hide()
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be exactly the same as @Slim's answer, but with simplified code that doesn't re-select the same elements again and again.  The `$()` selector in jQuery is fast, but there's no reason to keep selecting `$(this)` 7 times if we don't have to.

```js
$(".mobile-toggle").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass("inactive")) {
    $this.removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");

    //find current toggle element parent, then find next element(wrapper of the images) and finally find children image.
    var $platformImgs = $this.parent('.platform-toggle').next('.platform-images')
    $platformImgs.children('.mobile-image').show();

    $this.siblings('.desktop-toggle').removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    $platformImgs.children('.desktop-image').hide();
  }
});
```